# Joomla Advance search page is not woking

Tags: search, joomla

When we click on Advance search page, page is not come as blank, after enable php error module, we got this below error message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function jsdate_2_mysql() in /content/HostingPlus/f/r/xyz.com/web/new/plugins/search/events.php on line 48

Comment: Which PHP version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

1. check your php.ini file - make sure that mysql is enabled.
2. check out this link: http://www.somacon.com/p109.php